# how to check page skipping by changing the url in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am creating an online quiz system. Suppose for question1 url is /Q/Q1.php and for question2 url is /Q/Q2.php . I don't want users to directly skip to page Q2.php without solving question 1. How can i implement this ?

Comment: Save the last page in a session variable or cookie and compare it on page load.

Comment: You can manage their question index using sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as following

**Q1.php**

```
<html>
<p>What is stack overflow</p>
<form method="post" action="Q2.php">
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Website">Website<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer1" value="Software">Software<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="Q1"> 
</form>
</html>
```

**Q2.php**

```
<?php
if($_POST['answer1']==null)
{
    header('Location:Q1.php');
}
else
{
    ?>
    <p>This is question 2</p>
<form method="post" action="Q3.php">
<input type="radio" name="answer2" checked value="Website">Website<br>
<input type="radio" name="answer2" value="Sotware">Software<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="Q1"> 
</form>
<?php
}

?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to store the questions that have been answered in your session. That way you can check the session with each request to see if they are allowed to answer this question.

```
session_start(); // always start the session with each request

if (/* question was answered correctly */) {
    $_SESSION['questions'][] = $question_number;
} else {
    /* question was not answered correctly take action here */
}

// To check if they may proceed to the next question

if (in_array($question_number - 1, $_SESSION['questions'])) {
    /* Show the next question */
} else {
    echo "You didn't answer the last question yet!";
}
```